# How to run my ASP.NET Core 6 project using any 6.x.x .NET installed version

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, global

I'm mantaining a bundle of projects with ASP.NET Core 6, about 100 of them and increasing, and I usually have to open it, run it, check stuff, modify stuff, etc.

Projects were created by the same person (not me), and there are things a little deprecated, in example: Every time I open a project I need to edit the global.json file and change the .NET version to the version I have installed now. Now it is version 6.0.413 for me, but all the global.json files has a 6.0.100. I always have to manually change it on every project, and if I work on a new PC or I update my .NET version I have to check the exact number first and then update it, the same with my teammates, by using the command:

```
 dotnet --list-sdks
```

The output in my current machine is this, and every machine I use I get a different 6.0.x version installed

[image]

I think it's a little tedious, and when each project is deployed we have to specify which .NET version must be installed on the client. Is there a way to just make the project (try to) run with any installed version 6.0.X or 6.X.X of .NET? This is the fragment of global.json code that is killing me:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.413"
  }
}
```

The error I get when installed .NET version is not the same described at global.json

```
Error   NETSDK1141  Can't solve .NET SDK version as specified at global.json file in C:\Projects\asp.net-core-6\XXXXX\global.json.  XXXXX
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   127
```

Comment: This should not matter... it'll find the latest 6.x run-time on the machine regardless of minor version.  SDK will choose the latest version 6, run-time will choose latest version 6.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Comment: I have edit and add the full output of Visual Studio with the error message, in my case and for all projects and PCs of my office we need to specify the exact installed version

Comment: Looks like the SDK installed on that machine is 7 major version.  It can't find/resolve to a version 6, so it throws that error.  You can either install version 6 SDK, or specify version as 7.0.400... if the SDK is updated to 7.0.401, you don't need to change anything... it'll find the latest v7 available.

Comment: But as you can see in the screenshot I have also installed a 6.0.413, I'm going to uninstall the 7.x.x version, I'll tell you soon if working dude

Comment: hmm... you may have to use rollForward: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json#rollforward